# Nuxt.js run generate, global mixin (... is not a function)

Tags: nuxt.js, mixins

I have made some global mixes and they work fine as long as I make `run dev` command.
But when I make `run generate` I get an error in the console "is not a function".
Similar problems appear on the server when I connect external plugins, but do not happen in development mode.
I have tried different solutions but nothing helped.

Here is my nuxt.config (left only basic settings for demo). Pay attention to `plugins/seo.js`

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  srcDir: 'nuxt',
  ssr: false,
  plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/nuxt-quill-plugin', ssr: false },
    { src:'~plugins/vue-final-modal.js'},
    { src: '~plugins/notifications.js', mode: 'client' },
    '~plugins/persistedState.js',
    '~plugins/clickOutside.js',
    '~plugins/dateTimePicker.js',
    '~plugins/seo.js',
    "~plugins/location.js",
    "~plugins/fetchData.js"
  ],
  echo: {
     plugins: [ '~/plugins/echo.js' ]
  },
  components: true,
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    ['@nuxtjs/laravel-echo', { 
      broadcaster: 'pusher', 
      key: 'e27d2f2173c11d7b12c7',
      cluster: 'eu',
      forceTLS: true,
      authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
    }],
      'nuxt-laravel'
  ],
  build: {
   transpile: ["vue-final-modal", 'notifications', 'fetchData', 'location', 'seo', 'dom7'],
   vendor: ["vue-final-modal", 'notifications', 'fetchData', 'location', 'seo', 'dom7'],
    loaders: {
        cssModules: {
            localIdentName: '[local]', //Work
            modules: false
        },
        css: {
            localIdentName: '[local]'
        }
    }
  },
  generate: {
    vendor: ["vue-final-modal", 'notifications', 'nuxt-quill-plugin', 'fetchData', 'location', 'seo', 'dom7'],
    transpile: ["vue-final-modal", 'notifications', 'nuxt-quill-plugin', 'fetchData', 'location', 'seo', 'dom7'],
    loaders: {
        cssModules: {
            localIdentName: '[local]', //Work
            modules: false
        },
        css: {
            localIdentName: '[local]'
        }
    }       
},
}
```

And here is one of my mixins that breaks with the error "seoPath is not a function". Pay attention to `seoPath` method.

```js
import Vue from "vue"

if (!Vue.seo_dispatcher) {
  Vue.seo_dispatcher = true
  
  Vue.mixin({
        head() {
            return {
                title: this.seoTitle,
                meta: [
                    {
                        hid: 'description',
                        name: 'description',
                        content: this.seoDesc
                    },{
                        hid: 'title',
                        name: 'title',
                        content: this.seoTitle
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        data(){
            return {
                variableAliases: {
                    '#CITY#': 'city',
                    '#CITY_PRED#': 'city',
                    '#CITY_REGION#': 'region',
                    '#CITY_REGION_PRED#': 'region',
                    '#NAME#': 'seo',
                    '#MIN.PRICE#': 'min_price',
                    '#CATEGORY#': 'category',
                    '#PRODUCT#': 'product'
                }
            }   
        },  
      methods: {
          async dispatchSeo(to){
            if(this.$store){
                this.$store.dispatch('router/getSeo', to)
            }
          },
          // get city & area from store and suffix it to url
          // AND get language slug and prefix it ti url
          seoPath(slug){
              // if router object
              if(typeof slug === 'object') {
                let route = this.$router.resolve(slug)
                slug = route.href
              }         
              
              let slash = slug.endsWith('/')? '': '/';
              
              let url_location = [
                    this.$store.state.router.city.slug,
                    this.$store.state.router.area.slug
              ].filter((item) => {
                  return item !== null && item !== ''
              });
              
              return this.localePath(slug + slash + url_location.join('/'))
          },
          // get string and replace all variables with data form store using variable's aliase array
          replaceVariables(string){
            const reg = new RegExp('(#CITY#|#CITY_PRED#|#CITY_REGION#|#CITY_REGION_PRED#|#NAME#|#MIN.PRICE#|#CATEGORY#|#SUBCATEGORY#|#PRODUCT#)', 'gi');
            return string.replaceAll(reg, (match) => {
                
                let modal = this.variableAliases[match]
                
                if(this.$store.state.router[modal] && this.$store.state.router[modal].name)
                    return  this.$store.state.router[modal].name
                else
                    return '';
    
            })
          }
      },
      computed: {
          seoH1(){
              if(this.$store)
                if(this.$store.state.router.seo && this.$store.state.router.seo.meta_h1)
                    return this.replaceVariables(this.$store.state.router.seo.meta_h1)
                else
                    return ''
          },
          seoTitle(){
              if(this.$store)
                if(this.$store.state.router.seo && this.$store.state.router.seo.meta_title)
                    return this.replaceVariables(this.$store.state.router.seo.meta_title) 
                else
                    return ''
          },
          seoDesc(){
              if(this.$store)
                if(this.$store.state.router.seo && this.$store.state.router.seo.meta_desc)
                    return this.replaceVariables(this.$store.state.router.seo.meta_desc) 
                else
                    return ''
          },
          seoText(){
              if(this.$store)
                if(this.$store.state.router.seo && this.$store.state.router.seo.meta_text)
                    return this.replaceVariables(this.$store.state.router.seo.meta_text)
                else
                    return '' 
          }
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: **What** _is not a function_?

Comment: @kissu "seoPath is not a function" - method that is defined in the mixin

Comment: Where is it called? Do you really need to transpile your own `seo` btw? Also, be careful because mixins are actually deprecated.

Comment: @kissu it is called in templates, directly in nuxt-link like `<nuxt-link :to="seoPath('/')"></nuxt-link>`. 
Not sure if I need transpile. These were my tries to make the code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that files from the `plugins` directory are not compiled into the project's build files, but remain as links to files in the plugins directory. In my case, the project builts in a directory that was outside the nuxt folder, therefore, there was no access to files from the plugins folder.

Moving the project build path inside the nuxt directory solved the problem.